# How to send an e-mail after adding the product to the cart in magento 2?

Tags: php, email, magento, events, magento2

Unfortunately, so far I am a complete beginner in creating a module in magento.
I need to send an email after adding the item to the cart.

As I understand it, I need to use the checkout_cart_product_add_after event

I created some files, but I don't understand how to send an email after adding the item to the cart

My/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="email_after_adding_product" instance="My\Module\Observer\SendEmailForCart"/>
</event>
```

My/Module/Observer/SendEmailForCart.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use My\Module\Helper\Email;

class SendEmailForCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $helperEmail;

    public function __construct(
        Email $helperEmail
    ) {
        $this->helperEmail = $helperEmail;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        return $this->helperEmail->sendEmail();
    }
}
```

My/Module/Helper/Email.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Helper;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    public function __construct(

    )
    {

    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        try {
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Please tell, what code I need to write in the Email.php file?
And do I need to create any additional files or modify the ones I showed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
* Recipient email config path
*/
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
*/
protected $_transportBuilder;

/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
*/
protected $inlineTranslation;

/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
*/
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
* @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
*/
protected $storeManager;
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
*/
protected $_escaper;

/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
* @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
* @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
*/
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}

/**
 * Post user question
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    if (!$post) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

    try {
        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($post);
        $error = false;

        $sender = [
            'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name']),
            'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['email']),
        ];

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'.$e->getMessage())
        );
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But when I run setup:di:compile the compiler gives an error:

Errors during compilation: My \ Module \ Helper \ Email
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \ Magento \ Framework \ App \ Helper \ Context. Current type: \ Magento \ Framework \ App \ Action \ Context; File:
/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/My/Module/Helper/Email.ph

I tried to change the path to Context from
\ Magento \ Framework \ App \ Action \ Context 
on
\ Magento \ Framework \ App \ Helper \ Context 

After that, the compilation was successful, but the product is not added to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Make a reasearch on your own in vendor/magento. There are many places where emails are sent. Look for $transport or $transportObject variable (don't remember)